# Subversion - Can I set auto-props on the server side?

Tags: svn, mime

I'm maintaining a SVN server and on user needs to commit many adobe illustrator files (ie `*.ai`). I can use the auto-props in their config to set it as a binary file so that it won't be in the mailing list commits. However I'd like to make this as easy as possible. Is there something I can set in the SVN server config, so that it (ie the server) will automatically set the correct `svn:mime-type`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible. There is a long standing [feature request](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=1974) for broadcasting configs to client. It's not presently due until 2.0, or later.

The closest you can come is to use hooks. Either with a pre-commit to prevent incorrectly configured clients from submitting the wrong data. Or a post-commit to retro-fix wrong data.

Neither is great and I believe the latter is even advised against.

Comment: It is possible with SVN 1.8 client.

Comment: client != server side (as specified in question)

Comment: @Jesse the repository-dictated configuration is a client-side feature. However, auto-props are set on the server/repository side and help push the config to clients. This answer is not actual anymore and is wrong.

Comment: @bahrep The OP mentions auto-props and is aware of the auto-props functionality which is set, configured and modified **client side per repository**. For instance, if you manage hundreds or thousands of SVN repositories, then this configuration would have to be done **per repository** and isn't "easy" (per what the OP was looking for). This **per repository** configuration would also have to be explained to the owner of each repository and they could back-out the configuration if you don't prevent it with hooks. Dan's answer is correct given the original question.

Comment: @Jesse There is client's side auto-props, and `svn:auto-props` which is server- or repository- side. In either case someone has to explain the owner or he has to read the documentation to implement any server or repository side feature.

Comment: @bahrep Give me a configuration change that I can make to my server’s Subversion configuration file (i.e. subversion.conf) that will force all particular file extensions (i.e. *.ai) to be binary files for all Subversion repositories on the host. Pretty sure this is what “Is there something I can set in the SVN server config” means.

Comment: @Jesse The stuff you look for is called "automation". You should apply `svn:auto-props` with the wanted values to your existing repositories. When you add a new repository, just add a step that will add the necessary `svn:auto-props`.

Comment: @bahrep I'd suggest reading the OP's question again... "make this as easy as possible" != "apply svn:auto-props with the wanted values to your existing repositories. When you add a new repository, just add a step that will add the necessary svn:auto-props". This will be my last comment. Good luck to you.

Answer (score 6):

Apache Subversion 1.8 introduced the [Repository Dictated Configuration](http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config) feature which requires **SVN 1.8 client**. (1.8 server is not required, in other words).

With Subversion 1.8, you can configure auto-props patterns within a repository using the new Subversion [`svn:auto-props` inherited property](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.advanced.props.html#svn.advanced.props.inheritable).

For example, setting `svn:auto-props` value to `*.bmp = svn:mime-type=image/bmp` property on the root of your repository (or repository path that represents a root of a project) will result into *each newly added* bitmap file to have the MIME type applied automatically.

You can store multi-line values in Subversion properties, so you can add the following (quite standard) svn:needs-lock and MIME pattern to `svn:auto-props`:

```
*.bmp = svn:mime-type=image/bmp;svn:needs-lock=*
*.gif = svn:mime-type=image/gif;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ico = svn:mime-type=image/x-icon;svn:needs-lock=*
*.jpeg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg;svn:needs-lock=*
*.jpg = svn:mime-type=image/jpeg;svn:needs-lock=*
*.png = svn:mime-type=image/png;svn:needs-lock=*
*.tif = svn:mime-type=image/tiff;svn:needs-lock=*
*.tiff = svn:mime-type=image/tiff;svn:needs-lock=*    
*.doc = svn:mime-type=application/msword;svn:needs-lock=*
*.jar = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odc = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.chart;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odf = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.formula;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odg = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.graphics;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odi = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.image;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odp = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.presentation;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ods = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.spreadsheet;svn:needs-lock=*
*.odt = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.oasis.opendocument.text;svn:needs-lock=*
*.pdf = svn:mime-type=application/pdf;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ppt = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.ms-powerpoint;svn:needs-lock=*
*.ser = svn:mime-type=application/octet-stream;svn:needs-lock=*
*.swf = svn:mime-type=application/x-shockwave-flash;svn:needs-lock=*
*.vsd = svn:mime-type=application/x-visio;svn:needs-lock=*
*.xls = svn:mime-type=application/vnd.ms-excel;svn:needs-lock=*
*.zip = svn:mime-type=application/zip;svn:needs-lock=*
```

Answer (score 3):

While there is no great answer to this, you can use [svn_apply_autoprops.py](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_apply_autoprops.py) which I wrote to apply your standard auto-props to a working copy to bring all the files there into compliance.

Comment: The link to svn_apply_autoprops.py seems to be broken. Searching for the filename gives me [this copy in Apache](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/contrib/client-side/svn_apply_autoprops.py) which is probably the same file.

Comment: Yes, that's the new location.  The Subversion source code moved from svn.collab.net to svn.apache.org when we joined the Apache Software Foundation.

Comment: Don't think the script is actual after implementation of Repository Dictated Configuration: http://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#repos-dictated-config